# IDEA: hot to remove top line in editor?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, view, editor, breadcrumbs

There is my first question in stackoverflow

[image: click to see image]

I'm looking at the preference but not found any solution.

How to disable or remove this line?

Comment: Please add more info about what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known as the breadcrumb menu for current code position.

To disable it from showing, Go to **File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance**

And Find and un-tick 'Show breadcrumbs'.

[image]